# change onchange event of dynamic created select to populate another dynamic created select

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have 2 select boxes with id **select1** and **otherselect1**. I fire an onchange event on **select1** to append data to **otherselect1**.

Now I dynamically add multiple of these select box combinations by increasing the id to +1. Eg: **select2 and otherselect2**, **select3 and otherselect3**.

the problem is that how do I write the onchange event so that if I change **select2** it only affects the data of **otherselect2**, similarly for **select3** and **otherselect3**.

Code:

```
    $('.select_type').on('change', function() {
        var channel_type = $(this).val();

        return  $.ajax({
            url: __SITE.baseUrl ,
            data: "channel_type=" + channel_type
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    var total = data.length;
                    $(this).next('.select_user').html('');
                    $(this).next('.select_user').append($('<option/>', {value: '', text : 'Choose One'}));
                    for(var i=0; i < total; i++)
                    {
                        $(this).next('.select_user').append($('<option/>', {value: data[i]['id'], text : data[i]['name']}));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

adding **onclick="javascript_function(this.id)"** to all **select1** and using this id in javascript_function to call the corresponding **otherselect1**

Answer (score 1):

Keep similar class name to all `select` and `otherselect` respectively, and use `next()` to append data selected from `.select` dropdown to `.otherselect`. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$('.select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).next('.other-select').append($('<option>', {
    text: $(this).val()
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="select">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
  <select class="other-select">
</select>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="select">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
  <select class="other-select">
</select>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="select">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
  <select class="other-select">
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow it is not working in my case. here is my js code. Not allowing me to paste code. Says too long. editing it in the ques.

Comment: $(this).next('.other-select').val(); gives undefined.

Comment: share you code in a fiddler, so that can look into it.

Comment: Thanx for the help Rajesh